# Scrapy json output missing comma

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and have been trying to figure this out for some time now. Thanks in advance.
I wanted to get a list of links from different pages. Each parse method yields an object with a list of links but the output file just dumps these objects without putting them in a list so it's not valid json.

The output is

```
{"links": *list of links*}
{"links": *list of links*}
```

But I'd like to see it in a list

```
[{"links": *list of links*},
{"links": *list of links*}]
```

Run it with `$ scrapy crawl links -o links.json`

```
class LinksSpider(scrapy.Spider) :
    name = "links"

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [
            "https://www.snerpa.is/net/isl/isl-th.htm",
            "https://www.snerpa.is/net/snorri/heimskri.htm"
        ]
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response) :
        linksList = []
        for link in response.xpath("//a/@href"):
            if link.get().index("/") < 2:
                linksList.append("https://www.snerpa.is/net/isl" + link.get()[1:])
        yield {
            "links": linksList
        }
```

EDIT: 
Scrapy version 2.1.0

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had previously copied a snippet and put it in settings.py
Changing this

```
from scrapy.exporters import JsonLinesItemExporter
class MyJsonLinesItemExporter(JsonLinesItemExporter):
    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        super(MyJsonLinesItemExporter, self).__init__(file, ensure_ascii=False, **kwargs)

FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'jsonlines': 'postscrape.settings.MyJsonLinesItemExporter',
    'jl': 'postscrape.settings.MyJsonLinesItemExporter',
    'json': 'postscrape.settings.MyJsonLinesItemExporter'
}
```

To this...

```
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter
class MyJsonItemExporter(JsonItemExporter):
    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        super(MyJsonItemExporter, self).__init__(file, ensure_ascii=False, **kwargs)

FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'jsonlines': 'postscrape.settings.MyJsonItemExporter',
    'jl': 'postscrape.settings.MyJsonItemExporter',
    'json': 'postscrape.settings.MyJsonItemExporter'
}
```

Fixed the issue

Comment: What is your scrapy version?

Answer (score 0):

There are different JSON exporters in Scrapy: JsonItemExporter and JsonLinesItemExporter. By default scrapy tries to guess what output do you want using file's extension.
It looks like you have output for a similar command:

```
$ scrapy crawl links -t jsonlines -o links.json
```

I'm not sure about old scrapy versions but in 2.0.1 this command works like you want:

```
$ scrapy crawl links -t json -o links.json
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer made me realize what I was doing wrong, see above.